# How to stop the execution of a request handling function in Express/Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express

I have an Express server that provides some computations as web services.

Computation time ranges from <1s to 10s.

Is there a way to stop the execution of a request-handling function (which is one of these computations) when a new request comes in ?

Basically, the question is : is there a way to stop the execution of a function in Javascript?
If not, is there a way I could terminate the thread that process the Express request ? 
If not, what would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript, including Node.js, is inherently single-threaded. If a CPU-bound function is running, nothing can interrupt it.

A better way of running these computations would be to fork another process to run them, which can then be stopped. For example:

fibo.js

```
function fibo(n) { // intentionally naive cpu-bound computation
  return n > 1 ? fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2) : 1;
}

process.on('message', function(n) {
  process.send(fibo(n));
});
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http'), cp = require('child_process');
var fibo;

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if(fibo) {
    fibo.kill();
    fibo = null;
    res.end('terminated');
  } else {
    fibo = cp.fork('./fibo.js');
    fibo.on('message', function(n) {
      res.end(n);
    });
    fibo.on('exit', function() {
      res.end('terminated by other request');
    });
    fibo.send(50);
  }
}).listen(8000);
```

**This is just an example. Please don't use as-is.** This server can only handle one concurrent request actually calculating something, and `child_process.fork` is *not* lightweight.